# Session constantly resets variable

Tags: session

I'm using sessions in wordpress but I have a problem where a variable I store keeps getting reset everytime I change page. it's "d_curr" and my code is the following :

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('parse_query', 'process_post' );
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

    function myStartSession() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['d_curr'] = 'USD';
        }
    }

    function myEndSession() {
        session_destroy ();
    }


    function process_post() {
        if( get_query_var('d_curr', 'same') != 'same' ) {
             $_SESSION['d_curr'] = get_query_var('d_curr', 'GBP');
        }
    }
```

I manage to change d_curr using the address bar, but everytime I change the page it gets reset to 'USD'

Comment: If the user is logged in why not use user meta instead? PHP Sessions don't interact well with caching systems and don't work on all server configurations, e.g. you'll get weird behaviour on WP Engine using PHP sessions

Comment: Also `get_query_var` isn't a replacement for `$_GET`, query variables are what're passed into the main `WP_Query` via rewrite rules, and they have a whitelist

Comment: Also, your query var will always get changed to GBP, the logic in `process_post` is broken. Those are also super generic function names, they should be prefixed

Comment: Thanks for the comments ! You advised to use metadata for the logged-in user, but I do not plan to log them in (i.e. ID/password), will it still work ? I'm just trying to keep track of user preferences, such as their language, for the duration of the session.

Comment: A logged in user doesn't have to be in the WP Admin area, they're still a logged in user, else none of the hooks you mentioned in your code would fire, `wp_login` will only fire if you log in. Perhaps you would be better off just using cookies